# IntArray.sort returns 0 everytime in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am new to kotlin. I am trying to sort Integer Array in kotlin with IntArray.sort(). I also used IntArray.sortedArray but got the same answer  0 for arraysize times

```
val sc = Scanner(System.in)
var n:Int = sc.nextInt()
var t:Int = sc.nextInt()
var tm = IntArray(100000)
var i:Int = 0
while(i<n){
    tm[i] = sc.nextInt()
    i++
}
tm.sort()
//var am = tm.sortedArray()
println("tm ${tm[0]}")
i = 0
while(i<n){
    println("${tm[i]}")
    i++
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because array is sorted in *ascending* mode. At the beginning it is filled only with `0` and after sorting the first element becomes `0`.

If you want to sort in *descending* order you should use [`sortDescending`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-descending.html)

Also, it would be better to create an array dynamically when you know its size. (You can replace it with list aswell)